# Why do changes from the parent context automatically go to the child context?

Tags: swift, core-data

```
// Getting the main context:
let mainContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

// Creating a child context:
let childContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
childContext.parent = mainContext
print(childContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent) // false

// Creating an object after creating a child context and setting its value
let wallet = WalletMO.init(context: mainContext)
wallet.currencyCode = "USD"

// Trying to get an object from a child context. And we get it successfully. Why?
if let walletFromChildContext = childContext.object(with: wallet.objectID) as? WalletMO {
   print(walletFromChildContext.currencyCode ?? "nil") // "USD"
}
```

I don't understand why changes from the parent context automatically get to the child context. Please explain why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've never obtained the wallet before, so the child context is reaching up to its parent to find the object. It's not automatically merging changes, it's just doing what it says in the documentation:

> If the object is not registered in the context, it may be fetched or returned as a fault.

If you create the wallet on the parent context, get a reference to it from the child context, *then* change it on the parent context, you will see that the child object does not change. Unregistered objects by definition have to come from the parent context or persistent store, otherwise you'd be creating multiple versions of the same object.